# How to change the page so that i won't see it happening using Jquery-mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using phonegap(1.8.1) and jquerymobile(1.1.0) together in my application

Now i open my application by opening the index.html page. My index.html contains lots of pages like

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
<div data-role="page" id="page3">
<div data-role="page" id="page4">
```

I need to open a page depending upon the flag which i have.
Currently the page1 opens by default. But suppose i want to open page2 as soon as my application opens then i did a `changePage()` in `pagebeforeshow` like this

```
$("#page1").on("pagebeforeshow", function(e) {
$.mobile.changePage("#page2");
});
```

But it always shows me page1 first and then it goes to page2. I want to directly open page2
How to do it?

Comment: Not clear enough as a question, and wheres the code? you're not new in SO, you should already know how to ask questions here.

Comment: Sometimes we feel like people with lot of knowledge doesn't require much explanation. Anyways I will Put my words as code and try to explain...

Comment: @Th0rndike Is it clear enough?

Comment: even i m not very sure what is the problem, but i think `pagebeforeshow` will load the page being loaded first and then switch to the new page which you are giving in `changePage` like this http://jsfiddle.net/dhavaln/Myhff/

Comment: @dhaval bro i explained in detail. Check my update

Comment: @Coder_sLaY well, it is clear enough now. I couldn't be sure about what you were needing before, but now i understand perfectly, which is a good thing for me in order to answer the question and for you in order to have some help with your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i think you're using the wrong event here. From [jqm-events](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html):

```
**pagebeforeshow**
Triggered on the "toPage" we are transitioning to, before the actual transition  
animation is kicked off. Callbacks for this event will recieve a data object
as their 2nd arg.  


 **pagebeforeload**

Triggered before any load request is made. Callbacks bound to this event can call  
preventDefault() on the event to indicate that they are handling the load request.  
 Callbacks that do this *MUST* make sure they call resolve() or reject() on the   
deferred object reference contained in the data object passed to the callback.
```

So, **pagebeforeload** is probably the default event you need to use in order to switch the page, since it's executed before LOADING the page, so you can't see it.

The main problem with **pagebeforeshow** is that when this event is triggered, there's already a page being loaded and ready to be shown. Calling a changePage() inside this event will only put in a queue the page transition to the new page to be shown after the currently being shown page. Maybe using this event and the "preventDefault()" technique explained in the jqm site could get you to the required behaviour, but i have never tried this so i can't help you further. Good luck.

EDIT: As the OP stated in the comments, the problem was the default transition of jqm. If a new page is loaded, automatic slide transition will be triggered, so the first page will be shown and then transitioned to the page called in changePage(). Solution is to avoid the transition like this:

```
$.mobile.changePage('#page', {transition:'none'});
```

that way, target page will be shown suddenly.

Comment: Hi Thorndike +1 for such a nice Response. Although you are conceptually right about pagebeforeshow and pagebeforeload. But nothing is getting fired if i use pagebeforeload, Not even a single console.log("Hi");

Comment: Why don't you give a try to the pagebeforeshow+preventDefault+reject technique? i think it's simple and could accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: How to reject.. I have like this $("#page1").on("pagebeforeshow", function(e) {e.preventDefault();   $.mobile.changePage("#page2");
});

Comment: Hi Thorndike... I got it... I was trying to do $.mobile.changePage('#page'); which used the default transition which is slide... If i do $.mobile.changePage('#page', {transition:'none'}); Then it works... Can you update this along with your post so that it will be help full for others.....

Comment: hehehheeh... P.S. i Loved your POST :D Grazie